# Password reset form is not showing by clicking reset Password laravel 5.4 authentication

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, reset-password

I'm trying to send the link through **mailtrap.io** when someone forgot the password, so when I try to send the link for resetting the password, the link is successfully sent but after clicking the **reset password** or the link that is provided there , it shows me again the view that I used for sending the link.
here is the  `link` I'v created.
I want to show the form that says :
`enter New Password`

`Confirm New Password`

```
Click here to reset your password !!! <br>
<a href="{{ $link = url('password/request',$token).'?email='.urlencode($user->getEmailForPasswordReset()) }}">{{ $link }}
</a>
```

** Route Files **

```
 Route::get('password/reset/{token?}', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
 Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
 Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
 Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
```

Comment: Can you add the code for your `route` and your `action`.

Comment: You can check that , I'v updated the post @Remul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two of your routes are clashing, if the token is provided the second route will never be hit, to fix this you have to remove `{token?}` from the first one:

Change:

```
Route::get('password/reset/{token?}', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
```

To this:

```
Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
```

Comment: Thank you so much that works for me :) You made my day